# Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS returns incorrect directory

Tags: android

My app has a button which allows the user to install some additional resources which can either be downloaded, or passed in by bluetooth. I make this button clickable if the relevant file is in the download directory.

```
String downloadDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
Log.d("MyApp","Download directory " + downloadDir);

File incomingFile = new File(downloadDir +"/myfile.zip");

if (incomingFile.exists()) {
  // Make button clickable
  }
else {
  incomingFile = new File(downloadDir +"/bluetooth/myfile.zip");
    if (incomingFile.exists()) {
      // Make button clickable
    }
  }
}
```

All of this works fine on one of my test devices, however, on an older HTC Wildfire phone (Android 2.2, API level 8) Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS is incorrect.

- The actual download directory is **/mnt/sdcard/downloads**
- The environment variable returns **/mnt/sdcard/Download**

I had kind of assumed that Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS would be a generic way of getting the right directory, and my searches don't show anyone else having the same issue.

So the question is am I safe to assume that this is just a quirk of that particular phone and the code is basically sound, or is there a more bullet proof way of getting the downloads directory that I am not aware of?

Comment: Mine returns `/storage/emulated/0/Download` instead of `/storage/emulated/legacy/Download`. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Sadly not. I implemented an awful bodge which checked file.exists against a range of possible options until it found the file.