# Java Parameter Passing Issue

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing

I'm still a beginner in Java and I'm creating a simple Android app. For that I need to create 2 folders when app is opened. I have created a getters and setter class to pass folder name parameter in the main class. But it doesn't work. Doesn't get any error. Please help me to fix this.

Getters and setters class

```
public class CommonClass {

private String folderName;

public CommonConfig(String folderName) {
    this.folderName = folderName;
}

public CommonConfig() {
}

public String getFolderName() {

    return folderName;
}

public void setFolderName(String folderName) {
    this.folderName = folderName;
}
```

}

Main Class

```
public class MainActivityClass extends Activity {
   private static final String TAG = "svsvsf";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            CommonClass video = new CommonClass();
            video.setFolderName("Video");

            CommonClass audio = new CommonClass();
            audio.setFolderName("Audio");

            TempVideoCreator(video,audio);

        }
    });
}


public void TempFolderCreator(CommonConfig video,CommonConfig audio){


    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + video + audio );

    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
          Log.d(TAG, "File already created");
    } else {
         Log.d(TAG, "faileddd");
    }
}
```

Comment: @OP, could you please tell what is not working ?

Comment: @LoganKulinski - Is this correct? Parameter passing correct? Folders are not creating. No errors found. I already added permissions to mainfiest.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ- Is this correct? Parameter passing correct? Folders are not creating. No errors found. I already added permissions to mainfiest.

Comment: @AnoopLL- No I need to create it seperately in the root. Not inside. Please help me. Is this parameter passing correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain few things to you...

While creating `new File()` we are passing the path as parameter like `new File("C://hiranya//video//newtextfile.txt")`. In your case you are passing objects of `Common` class to the `TempFolderCreator` and you are directly specifying that objects in the File, This is wrong. You set the folder name in  the `CommonClass` object and `TempFolderCreator` will be like

```
public void TempFolderCreator(CommonConfig video,CommonConfig audio){


File videoFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
        File.separator + video.getFolderName() );
 File audioFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
        File.separator + audio.getFolderName() );

boolean success = true;
if (!videoFolder .exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdirs();
}
if (!audioFolder .exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdirs();
}
//rest of the code
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much @Anoop LL . I learned from this. Thank you again. It works.

Comment: @hiranya  you are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

This may work. In this case I assumes you would like to create separate folders for video and audio. If you want to create audio folder inside video. Appends additional File.seperator between video and audio.

```
public void TempFolderCreator(CommonConfig video,CommonConfig audio){


File folderVideo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
        File.separator + video.getFolderName());
File folderAudio = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
        File.separator + audio.getFolderName());

boolean successVideo = true;
boolean successAudio = true;

if (!folderVideo.exists() ) {
    successVideo = folderVideo.mkdirs();
}
if (!folderAudio.exists() ) {
    successAudio = folderAudio.mkdirs();
}
//Arrange your error handling logic for Audio folder and video folder
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've, myself, recently struggled to make work this kind of code because Android return strange directory when you call `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` on some devices.

On my device I made it work with `myApplication.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()`, but I just needed a temporary directory.

See : [Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS returns incorrect directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041741/environment-directory-downloads-returns-incorrect-directory?noredirect=1#comment69611765_34041741)

**Note:** At first look, your code does not seems to compile. You may have simplified it for posting, but this does not help to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter passing is OK. But this expression is suspicious:

```
File.separator + video + audio
```

That is equivalent to

```
File.separator + video.toString() + audio.toString()
```

... which it is not likely what you want. To get the folder name, use the getter:
    video.getFolderName()

And also be careful to create each folder at one time.

Putting it all together:

```
private void createFolder(String folderName)
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folderName);

    boolean success = folder.exists();
    if (!success) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Folder "+folderName+" already created");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating folder "+folderName+" failed");
    }
}

public void TempFolderCreator(CommonConfig video,CommonConfig audio){
    createFolder(video.getFolderName());
    createFolder(audio.getFolderName());
}
```